# Upgrading VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox

I have been running a Debian (Wheezy) guest on a Window 7 host with Oracle VirtualBox.  I was recently prompted to upgrade the VirtualBox and did so to version 4.3.  Now I cannot get the guest additions upgraded.  When I run through the install of guest additions I get the following error:

```
Installing the windows systems drivers... fail!!!
Could not find x.org or XFree86 Windows System
```

Comment: are you running on CLI debian or Gnome debian ?

Comment: Hello, I am running command line interface debian.

Comment: well I bet you do not have a windows system install ? and this error seems OK if it's not blocking your boot.